# How can I call a cstudio action from a webpage in Crafter

Tags: content-management-system

I've created a webpage in Crafter CMS (version 2.5.2) whose purpose is to help edit a Crafter Component. I'm doing this in my page instead of in the CStudio Panel because I want to search/filter for specific components (I have 1000s). I'm editing the components using Crafter's In Context Editing capabilities, but I want to be able to call actions such as Create New, Delete, Approve & Publish, History, etc on a selected component. Is there any way I can do that from my web page along with the UI (e.g. Create New pops up normal Create New modal dialog, History pops up history dialog, etc.).

Comment: Just to add to this, I did see how to call a create new component via a URL (e.g. `<a target="_new_win" class="btn btn-xs btn-info btn-create" href="/studio/form?site=mysite&form=/component/mycomponent&path=/site/components/mycomponents&iceComponent=true">Create Revision Request</a>`), but it doesn't load it into a modal dialog. Seems like I really need to be able to call the same javascript that cstudio uses in it's edit panel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Crafter CMS uses a message pump between the preview pane and the studio application to inform the application of actions taken "in-context." within the preview pane. Messages (operations with metadata) are pumped by the system automatically between the two contexts (the studio application and the preview pane.)

"Edit" is currently a valid message/op.
"Delete" is currently a valid message/op.

However in 2.5.2 there is no "New" message/op.

In order to fire a New Op message you would need to register the message and build the handler (all Javascript) that fires the appropriate javascript APIs for the app.  To fire a New operation you only NEED a path to where the content will be created in the message as metadata.  The App already has code to look up permissions and check if which content types are available at that path.

Javascript files of interest:
Fire the message
/static-assets/components/scripts/guest.js

Handle the message
/static-assets/components/scripts/host.js

Declare the valid messages
/static-assets/components/scripts/crafter.js

Comment: Thanks, Russ. I don't see a delete message in the code, but maybe I'm missing something. It'd be great to have new content, delete, approve & publish, and history if you get a chance at some point to add these :-).